# How to Increment the text file and also the value inside the file by Batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file Foo.txt which contains value content0. I have to create a batch file which increment the text file like Foo1.txt, Foo2.txt.....Foo5.txt and also the values in the file content1, content2,...content5. The Foo1.txt should have the value content1

I have written the code to increment the file

```
@echo off

for /L %%i IN (1,1,5) do call :docopy %%i
goto end

:docopy
set FN=%1
set FN=%FN:~-3%

copy C:\Users\sindhu\Desktop\foo.txt foo%FN%.txt

:end
```

But I don't to write the code to increment the value inside the file. Please help me on this

Comment: Please rephrase you question, it's mind-bugging what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 1):

when I understand you question correct:

```
for /L %%i IN (1,1,5) do echo content%%i>foo%%i.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to stephan's answer,

First read the content of `foo.txt` into the variable `content` like so:

```
set /p content=<foo.txt
```

Then the final code will look like:

```
set /p content=<foo.txt
for /L %%i IN (1,1,5) do echo %content%%%i>foo%%i.txt
```

here `%content%` is replaced by the actual content that was read from `foo.txt`in all the files `foo%%i`.